# Can I manage 2 level access for my federation

Tags: permissions

I am investigating the possible use of CIVI CRM for my federation.
We are a hobby federation and our main clients are the local clubs.
The federation maintains the club's information and invoice these clubs once a year.
The Clubs themselves need to access their Club information to manage their members (add, modify, and delete)
Are these two levels of access possible in CIVI CRM?

Thank you for your time.
daniel

Answer (score 3):

Welcome. There are a few options to look at

1/ [Permissioned Relationships](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions)

2/ [Multisite systems](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/multisite/)

3/ [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this puts me on a track.

Comment: Cool - it would be good to know how you end up approaching this.